# Replace string with incremented value

Tags: php, css, parsing, string, iteration

I'm trying to write a CSS parser to automatically dispatch URLs in background images to different subdomains in order to parallelize downloads.

Basically, I want to replace things like

```
url(/assets/some-background-image.png)
```

with

```
url(http://assets[increment].domain.com/assets/some-background-image.png)
```

I'm using this inside a class that I eventually want to evolve into doing various CSS parsing tasks.

Here are the relevant parts of the class :

```
private function parallelizeDownloads(){
    static $counter = 1;
    $newURL = "url(http://assets".$counter.".domain.com";
```

The counter needs to be reset when it reaches 4 in order to limit to 4 subdomains.

```
    if ($counter == 4) {
        $counter = 1;
    }
    $counter ++;
    return $newURL;
}

public function replaceURLs() {
```

This is mostly nonsense, but I know the code I'm looking for looks somewhat like this. Note : $this->css contains the CSS string.

```
    preg_match("/url/i",$this->css,$match);
    foreach($match as $URL) {
        $newURL = self::parallelizeDownloads();
        $this->css = str_replace($match, $newURL,$this->css);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that wasn't very clear. Basically, how do I go about doing this so it works :D ? Right now it's replacing the strings correctly but not incrementing anything. Other then that, I'm looking for suggestions on how to go about doing this the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it working using preg_replace_callback. Here's the code :

```
private function parralelizeDownloads($matches) {
    static $counter = 1;
    $newURL = '';
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $newURL = "url(http://assets" . $counter . ".domain.com";
        if ($counter == 4) {
            $counter = 0;
        }
        $counter++;
    }
    return $newURL;
}

public function replaceURLs() {
    $this->css = preg_replace_callback("/url\(/i", Array($this, "parralelizeDownloads"), $this->css);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set $counter as a property of the class, and reference it as $this->counter, or self::$counter if you set it as a static property

You're calling self::parallelizeDownloads() in your public replaceURLs() method, so parallelizeDownloads() should really be defined as static

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've modified the code but I'm still not getting any incremented values. I think there's a problem with the replaceURLs() method...

Comment: You also probably want to use
if ($counter == 4) { 
    $counter = 0; 
} 
$counter ++; 
otherwise you reset the counter to 1, then immediately increment it to 2.

Your loop in replaceURLs() isn't doing much though, because you keep overriding $this->css

Comment: Thanks ! Looking at it it seems obvious now, that's why I wasn't seeing any increments in the replaced URLs. Still, how would I go about getting this to work ? Is preg_match the right tool for this ?